# how to ensure synchronized logic in two or more node process(child_process)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

For example, I have a master node process which produces 8 child_processes. Master process allocates http request and assigns it to 1 child_process (randomly or  round-robin).

If the logic in child_process is to read/update a certain file on disk, or to read/update a table field in database. Should I concern child_processes overriding each other's results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as each child works in a separate process they can reach external database in the same time. [IPC communication](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_message) can help to sync workers, but it depends on your task

Comment: Do you mean when appending content on the same file, the 8 child_processes may conflict with each other?

Comment: You mean database operation may conflict, that's what I get. Is it right? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "conflict"? For database there will be no conflict most of them are designed to work with concurrency. As for the file several processes may produce a mess after concurrent save operations, but it depends on how you manage write operations(WriteStream or sync writings may solve the problem)

Comment: need to sync writing is what I want to confirm - else processes will produce mess(I mean conflict) - so I need to have only one process to write file instead of all processes.  Thanks.